# Prove a function in 2 variables is onto

Tags: functions

Consider the function $h: N \times N \rightarrow N$ so that $h(a,b) = (2a +1)2^b - 1$, where $N=\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ is the set of natural numbers.

Prove that it is **onto**.

---

Tried taking various examples and value putting technique to see that most of values in the range are covered, which supports my intuition that the function is onto.
\begin{array}{cc|c} a & b & h(a,b) \\\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 0 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 & 5 \\ \vdots&\vdots & \vdots \end{array}

Comment: You could show it is bijective, by giving an explicit inverse, e.g. $b$ is the number of powers of $2$ dividing $c+1$ and $a=\dfrac{(c+1)/2^b - 1}{2}$.  If h(h^{-1}(c))=c and $h^{-1}(h(a,b))=(a,b)$ then $h$ is onto (and 1-to-1)

Comment: It will b much more obvious that $2^a(2b+1)$ is ontp the positive integers, For any positive integer can be expressed (uniquely, but we don't need that for onto) as a power of $2$ times an odd number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a natural number $n$ and let's prove that it is of the given form.

$$(2a+1)2^b = n+1$$

$n+1$ can be expressed as $2m$ or $2m+1$ for some $m$. In the first case, you can repeat the procedure with m, obtaining that $m=2^k$ for some $k$ or $m=2^j h$ where $h$ is of the form $2l + 1$.

So, in the end, you get that you can express $n+1$ as a number of the given form $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for any $n = h(a,b)$ for unknown $a,b$, express $n+1$ in binary. Can you now see an obvious candidate for $b$ and deduce $a$?